# How do I test Hibernate Database is okay, quickly

Tags: java, database, hibernate, h2, c3p0

When I start my application I test my internal database is okay as follows:

```
HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
```

This is a H2 database. I'm using Hibernate on top with c3p0 pooling.

Trouble is it takes **one minute** to decide that it cannot being a transaction, I'd like it to retry within 10 seconds. I've looked at c3p0 properties and cannot see anything that does this.

*** Update ***
Comment made me realize that HibernateUtil.beginTransaction() was hiding what I was doing so replaced with:

```
System.out.println("Get Session"+new Date());
Session session = com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.HibernateUtil.getSession();
System.out.println("Get Txn"+new Date());
Transaction t = session.getTransaction();
System.out.println("Set Timeout"+new Date());
t.setTimeout(10);
System.out.println("Begin Txn"+new Date());
session.beginTransaction();
System.out.println("Commit"+new Date());
t.commit();
```

Output is

```
Get SessionWed Nov 21 12:15:56 GMT 2012
Get TxnWed Nov 21 12:16:27 GMT 2012
Set TimeoutWed Nov 21 12:16:27 GMT 2012
Begin TxnWed Nov 21 12:16:27 GMT 2012
FailedWed Nov 21 12:16:46 GMT 2012
```

So it seems 30 seconds is spent getting a Session (unclear how it can even get a Session as the database is corrupt) and then 19 seconds trying to begin transaction

whereas when the database is fine, the timings are a few seconds

```
Get SessionWed Nov 21 12:23:57 GMT 2012
Get TxnWed Nov 21 12:23:59 GMT 2012
Set TimeoutWed Nov 21 12:23:59 GMT 2012
Begin TxnWed Nov 21 12:23:59 GMT 2012
CommitWed Nov 21 12:23:59 GMT 2012
```

So the main problem seems to be that it takes a longtime to (sort of) get a Session when db corrupt

Comment: Does this thread helps you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635047/transaction-timeout-not-working-on-hibernate-with-oracle

Comment: thx, helps but doesnt solve problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you didn't configure `acquireRetryAttempts` for your C3P0 and it tries to connect to the database for 30 times which is the default value. Decrease this value and you'll get it much faster.

Also there are options you might want to tune:

- `acquireRetryDelay` (default: 1s)
- `breakAfterAcquireFailure` (default: false)

Comment: I decreased "hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts" from 30 to 10 (as I need some retries for when actually using app normally) and that has reduced timeout to a more acceptable level, although still greater than 10 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: HibernateUtil.getsessionfactory().opensession();

In place of:HibernateUtil.getSession();

Comment: I dont have that class in my HibernateUtil class, but what would be the purpose of changing that.